# Analysing a Python bytecode

Tags: python-3.x, bytecode

In the following Python bytecode, I would like to understand why the value of `i` is not incremented just before `JUMP_ABSOLUTE` ?

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis("""for i in range(4):
...     print(i)
... """)
  1           0 SETUP_LOOP              24 (to 26)
              2 LOAD_NAME                0 (range)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (4)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              8 GET_ITER
        >>   10 FOR_ITER                12 (to 24)
             12 STORE_NAME               1 (i)

  2          14 LOAD_NAME                2 (print)
             16 LOAD_NAME                1 (i)
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             20 POP_TOP
             22 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           10
        >>   24 POP_BLOCK
        >>   26 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             28 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: What is your *own* analysis of the byte-code? And why do you need it? What is the problem you need to solve by this analysis? Where did you get the byte-code from?

Comment: And to help you understand more about what's happening, you should probably read more about [the `range` ***class***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range).

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/dis.html#bytecodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The evolution of `i` is simply done at the line 10 by calling the magic method `__next__` of `range`.